# Saving data from SQLite data base into a Variable

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt, qdialog

I'm trying to save the username from the database into a variable to use in another QDialog, but the variable is blank when I try to use it in the other dialog

```
qry.prepare("select nome from Users where email='"+user+"' and senha='"+password+"'");
 if(qry.exec()) {
   int count=0;
   while(qry.next()) {
    ui->label_2->setText(qry.value(0).toString());
     count++;
   }

   if (count == 1) {
     usuario = ui->label_2->text();
     ui->errologin->setText("");
     logado= true;
     this->hide();

   }
```

This is how i'm trying to call it in the other Dialog:

```
ui->label->setText(log.usuario);
```

And this ist the variable declaration in the header file:

```
public:
  explicit login(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~login();
  bool logado;
  QString usuario;
```

Comment: unrelated but don't build queries by concatenating strings, use prepared statements instead otherwise you'll have sql injection vulnerabilities

Comment: we'll probably need a [mre] to help

Comment: better now? and i'm fist showing it in a label and after saving in the variable so I can see if it is getting the user name correctly (it is)

Comment: @GuilhermeLeal provide a **real** [mre]

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing that you could do better, instead of this:

```
qry.prepare("select nome from Users where email='"+user+"' and senha='"+password+"'");
```

Replace it by:

```
qry.prepare("select nome from users where email=? and senha=?");
qry.bindValue(0, user);
qry.bindValue(1, password);
```

Please, don't build your queries concatenating strings.

Other than that, there is no way to tell where is your mistake, because you don't provide a minimal reproducible example, as @AlanBirtles and @eyllanesc have requested. I don't see the problem in the code you provided, it may be somewhere hidden in the code that you **don't** show.

Another advice: trying to reduce your problem to a minimal test program may help you to find the problem by yourself. For instance, if you doubt about your usage of the QSqlQuery class, then put your query in a console program and see if it returns the correct results. If it still doesn't work right, then post your (full) test program here in SO.